# Is there any way to regexp CSS to increase a property value depending on their position?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am preparing a web with `@keyframe`-animations. To get the desired effect currently I have the following code...

index.htm

```
<article>
    <div>Section 1</div>
    <div>Section 2</div>
    <div>Section 3</div>
    <div>Section 4</div>
    ...
</article>
```

style.css

```
article {
    ...
}
        article > div {
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: block;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            /**/
            animation-name: animation-example;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
        }
                    article > div:nth-of-type(1) {
                        animation-delay: 0.0s;
                    }
                    article > div:nth-of-type(2) {
                        animation-delay: 0.2s;
                    }
                    article > div:nth-of-type(3) {
                        animation-delay: 0.4s;
                    }
                    article > div:nth-of-type(4) {
                        animation-delay: 0.8s;
                    }
                    ...
```

As you can see, each `<div></div>` node has the same animation, BUT with different delay, increasing it by 0.2s.

The question is, **in pure CSS**, is it possible to "regex-it" somehow to make it work for every item placed there without having to set it for each one?

If not possible in pure CSS, is it possible to achieve this in any CSS metalanguage like SASS, LESS, ...?

If also no, what would be the best way to get this? (JavaScript, PHP, ...)

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: I choose the LESS question as it was the nearest to my needs. Said that, I probably will go for the [@Raymond Nijland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841029/is-there-any-way-to-regexp-css-to-increase-a-property-value-depending-on-their-p?noredirect=1#comment84686909_48841029) and use PHP to set these special CSS variables.

Comment: it is also possible to generate dynamic CSS with PHP.. -> https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/ .. simply make a loop in PHP

Comment: @RaymondNijland That is what I was thinking about when I wrote the last "If also no" question, but I wanted it to be the last option. Thanks anyway for the suggestion and the link, will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not possible in pure CSS, you can do it in LESS with a recursive mixin:

```
.generate-delays(10); // 10 would be your maximum number of items
                      // - set higher if needed

.generate-delays(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  article>div:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
    animation-delay: ((@i - 1) * 0.2s);
  }
  .generate-delays(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```